# How to adjust the width of a custom upload button automaticly?

Tags: css, forms, button, file-upload

I am working on a custom upload button for a web-form on the website, but can't handle the width properly.

I overwrote the default input-tag and implemented a custom label. I want the label to also show the uplaoded file-name, therefore I splitted it into two sections (1. Text and 2. Upload-Button).

When the focus is on the upload Button, I need a border to appear.
But the label-object (with the border) is always shorter then the 2 span-objects inside of it. Also if I adjust the text inside the spans, the label gets wider but still crops before the end of the second span (it always crops on the same part of the text... around 3 letters are always outside of the label-border).

So my question: How can I adjust the width of the label to always fit the two spans inside of it.

For your understanding, here an example:

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    margin: auto auto;
}

.inputFile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.inputFile + label {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.inputFile + label > span.labelFileButton  {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 2%;
}
.inputFile + label > span.labelFileAnzeige  {
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2%;
}

.inputFile:focus + label,
.inputFile + label:hover {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="texteingabe">
        <label for="texteingabe">Texteingabe</label>


        <input type="file" id="uploadInput" class="inputFile">
        <label for="uploadInput" class="labelFile">
            <span class="labelFileButton">
                Eine Datei hochladen
            </span>
            <span class="labelFileAnzeige">
                Keine Datei ausgewählt
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you very much in advance for any input or help!

Best,
Arthur